# Logic app workflow failing with error "VNetPrivatePortNotConfigured"

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I have configured stateful logic app workflow using `service bus queue message(peek-lock)` connector. After processing message, the "Complete" action failing to remove message from queue using `MessageId` and throwing exception as
[image]

Tried to test after updating the below logic app configurations but in that case workflow itself was not triggering

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after changing the built-in "Complete Message" action connector to a managed action connector.

Comment: Glad it started Working

Answer (score 0):

> Logic app workflow failing with error "VNetPrivatePortNotConfigured"

To remove above error you need to do below steps :

Firtsly create vnet in same location as of logic app and service bus and then configure outbound traffic as below:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Then click Configuration and then click on general settings and change VNet Private Ports to 2:

[image]

By following above steps the error you are getting will be resolved.

Comment: VNet is in the same location as a logic app and service bus. After setting `VNet Private Ports` to 2, getting different error as `The service provider action failed with error code 'ServiceOperationFailed' and error message 'The Service bus receiver was not found to perform operation 'completeMessage' on message id '2927fc4-225a-4b5b-a262-181909744906'`